# Combining Active Record group, join, maximum & minimum

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to get to grips with the Active Record query interface.  I have two models:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :datapoints
  attr_accessible :genre
end

class Datapoint < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :movie  
  attr_accessible :cumulative_downloads, :timestamp
end
```

I want to find the incremental downloads per genre for a given time period.

So far I've managed to get the maximum and minimum downloads per movie within a time period, like so:

```
maximums = Datapoint.joins(:movie)
    .where(["datapoints.timestamp > ?", Date.today - @timespan])
    .group('datatpoints.movie_id')
    .maximum(:cumulative_downloads)
```

This then allows me to calculate the incremental per movie, before aggregating this into the incremental per genre.

Clearly this is a bit ham-fisted, and I'm sure it would be possible to do this in one step (and using hash conditions).  I just can't get my head around how.  Can you help?

Much appreciated!

Derek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will allow you to calculate maximum per genre:

```
Movie.joins(:datapoints).where(datapoints: {timestamp: (Time.now)..(Time.now+1.year)}).group(:genre).maximum(:cumulative_downloads)
```

**Edit 1**

You can get the diffs in a couple of steps:

```
rel = Movie.joins(:datapoints).where(datapoints: {timestamp: (Time.now)..(Time.now+1.year)}).group(:genre)
mins = rel.minimum(:cumulative_downloads)
maxs = rel.maximum(:cumulative_downloads)
res = {}
maxs.each{|k,v| res[k] = v-mins[k]}
```

**Edit 2**

Your initial direction was almost there. All you have to do is calculate the diff per movie in the SQL and stage the data so you can collect it with one pass. I'm sure there's a way to do it all in SQL, but I'm not sure it will be as simple.

```
# get the genre and diff per movie
result = Movie.select('movies.genre, MAX(datapoints.cumulative_downloads)-MIN(datapoints.cumulative_downloads) as diff').joins(:datapoints).group(:movie_id) 
# sum the diffs per genre
per_genre = Hash.new(0)
result.each{|m| per_genre[m.genre] += m.diff}
```

**Edit 3**

Including the movie_id in the select and the genre in the group:

```
# get the genre and diff per movie
result = Movie
    .select('movies.movie_id, movies.genre, MAX(datapoints.cumulative_downloads)-MIN(datapoints.cumulative_downloads) as diff')
    .joins(:datapoints)
    .group('movies.movie_id, movies.genre') 
# sum the diffs per genre
per_genre = Hash.new(0)
result.each{|m| per_genre[m.genre] += m.diff}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  What I'm really after is the incremental downloads per genre for a given time period.  i.e the difference in the cumulative total between the beginning and the end.  Do you know if there is a way to get to this?

Comment: I hope I got what you're trying to achieve. I couldn't figure out how to do it with a single query. See my above edit for two.

Comment: I'm learning tonnes here, and this is really helpful.  However it isn't quite the result I need.  Currently it's returning the min / max of all the individual movies within a genre.  However what I'm looking to do is calculate the incremental downloads per genre within a timeframe.  This might be by 1) calculating the min (starting) downloads for each movie 2) summing them to get the min (starting) downloads for the genre 3) do the same for max and 4) find the difference per genre. Another way might be by summing incremental views per movie by genre. Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the semantics? what does datapoint mean in your context and what is the meaning of cumulative downloads of a datapoint?

Comment: A datapoint is a piece of information from a 3rd party about the cumulative all-time downloads of a movie at a point in time.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David, you're a STAR.  I also included the movie_id in the select and the genre in the group (as per edit 3) above.  Let me know if this isn't right.

Comment: Including the movie_id in the select is helpful in case you need to use it after the query. I don't see where you need to do that. Including the genre in the group is redundant as far as I can tell, since grouping by id is more granular in the first place, so it won't change the result. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: I found that if I didn't include them I got the error message "PG::Error: ERROR:  column "movies.genre" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"